# Revisiting the question on conditional expectation of a uniform point chosen out of a triangle with vertices (0,0),(1,0),(0,2)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is a question from my intro to probability text book, and I saw that another person asked the same question before, but I would like to see the derivation, instead of using the obvious figuring-out-from-mean method in the two answers.

Since $X,Y$ are uniformly distributed, I found that $f_{x,y}(x,y) = 2 \left(\frac{1}{\text{area}}\right)$ and $f_y(y)=\frac{2-y}{y}$ for $x$ is in such $\left[0,\frac{2-y}{2}\right]$, and I come out a conditional expectation of $E[X|Y=y] = \frac{2}{2-y}$ (using $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_y(y)}$).

However, the conditional expectation of $X$ conditioned on $Y=y$, is $E[X|Y=y]=\frac{2-y}{4}$, for $0<y<$ on the solution manual.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: It would have made sense to link to the other question you found.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I haven't read all of it since part of it seems garbled (what's "y4"?), but at the beginning, why is the density function $2$ over the area and not $1$ over the area?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, area of this triangle is $1$, so the joint density function is 
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$, if $(x,y)$ belongs to the triangle. Second, $f_Y(y)=\int\limits_0^{(2-y)/2} 1\,dx=\frac{2-y}{2}$, $y\in(0,2)$. Therefore for any $y\in(0,2)$
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{2}{2-y}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\left\{0<x<\frac{2-y}{2}\right\}}.
$$
This is the pdf of uniform distribution $U(0,\frac{2-y}{2})$. Its expectation is the middle of segment:
$$
\mathbb E(X|Y=y) = \int_0^{(2-y)/2} \dfrac{2x}{2-y}\, dx=\frac{2-y}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I should have integrated to (2-y)/2 instead of 1.

Comment: @AmosKu After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).